# StructureMap and SqlCacheDependency

Tags: sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm trying to enable SqlCacheDependency through my StructureMap IoC, I'm using LinqToSql I have the code done to take care of the Linq Caching but not quite sure how to go about setting up the SqlCacheDependency as it requires putting this in a global.asa file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["Catalog"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
}
```

However my repository doesn't use a global.asa as its just a library (.dll) not a web application.

Any ideas how to do this? Maybe put whats in the application_start method into the constructor of my repository?

Comment: Apparently adding it to my constructor didn't work...I get an invalid object referecne exception... I am thinking of just dropping the IoC / StructureMap patter... and going back to putting the DAL back into the main project... I'm not really gaining anything using StructureMap anyhow

Comment: You can gain a lot by using StructureMap and IoC in general.  The biggest gain for me was mocking my IBATIS.NET mappers so I could unit test our service layer and domain classes.  I strongly encourage you to use IoC to make unit testing much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving that code into a constructor should be fine.

I often place a static Initialize() method on anything that requires explicit initialization.  If my code is sanitary for external use I also throw my own UninitializedException if a method is invoked before the Initialize method is used.

My Global.asax tends to contain several blah.Initialize() invocations as a result.